# What guidelines should I use when choosing a sleeping bag liner?

Tags: sleeping-bags

I am 179-180cm (about 5.9ft) tall. I bought a [Thermolite Reactor Compact Plus](https://www.seatosummit.co.uk/products/travel-liners/thermolite-reactor-compact-plus/) sleeping bag liner. By specification it is 183cm, (6ft), however I did not count that the "head-end" also wraps one's head. So it feels to me that it is quite short. However, I managed to tighten the strap on the head, so technically I fit into it. Bear in mind that this is the first time I've tried sleeping bag liners, so it might be that I am just not used to it.

Are there any general guidelines for choosing a sleeping bag liner size?

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping bags come in a variety of sizes (e.g., https://www.outdoors.org/articles/amc-outdoors/how-to-fit-a-sleeping-bag). The most common being regular and long (sometimes there is a short and sometimes there is a women's regular and long). The typical regular fits people up to 6' tall and a long fits people up to 6' 6". Of course there is some variability across bag designs and people's preference. As you are just under 6' tall, you might fit in a regular bag, but you might be more comfortable in a long bag. Typically you want the shortest bag that you are comfortable since that will be the warmest.

The general guideline on liner size is to buy a liner that matches the size of your sleeping bag.